# Extracting query string value

Tags: tcl

How to extract the username value from this query string (HTTP url-encoded): `username=james&password=pwd` in Tcl?

I can get it through Java's `request.getParameter("username");` but how to get using Tcl?

Answer (score 2):

The first stage is to split the query string up, and form a dictionary of it (which isn't strictly correct, but I'm guessing you don't care about the case where someone puts multiple username fields in the query string!). However, you also need to decode the encoding of the contents, and that's pretty awful:

```
proc QueryStringToDict {qs} {
    set mapping {}
    foreach item [split $qs "&"] {
        if {[regexp {^([^=]+)=(.*)$} $item -> key value]} {
            dict set mapping [DecodeURL $key] [DecodeURL $value]
        }
    }
    return $mapping
}
proc DecodeURL {string} {
    # This *is* tricky! The URL encoding of fields is way nastier than you thought!
    set mapped [string map {+ { } \[ "\\\[" \] "\\\]" $ "\\$" \\ "\\\\"} $string]
    encoding convertfrom utf-8 \
            [subst [regsub -all {%([[:xdigit:]]{2})} $string {[format %c 0x\1]}]]
}

set qs "username=james&password=pwd"
set info [QueryStringToDict $qs]
puts "user name is [dict get $info username]"
```

In 8.7 (currently in alpha) it'll be much simpler to do that inner encoding; there won't need to be that `subst` call in there for example. But you haven't got that version of Tcl; nobody has (except for people who insist on being right on the bleeding edge and get themselves into trouble over it).

Comment: If you knew everything was ASCII, you'd be able to skip the calls to `DecodeURL`; that would work for your trial data, but doesn't work in general.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a CGI environment, where the environment will contain

```
REQUEST_METHOD=GET
QUERY_STRING='username=james&password=pwd'
```

or

```
REQUEST_METHOD=POST
CONTENT_LENGTH=27
# and stdin contains "username=james&password=pwd"
```

then use [tcllib's `ncgi` module](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/ncgi/ncgi.md#14)

```
$ cat > cgi.tcl
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require ncgi
::ncgi::parse
array set params [::ncgi::nvlist]
parray params

$ printf "username=james&password=pwd" | env REQUEST_METHOD=POST CONTENT_LENGTH=27 ./cgi.tcl
params(password) = pwd
params(username) = james

$ env REQUEST_METHOD=GET QUERY_STRING='username=james&password=pwd' ./cgi.tcl
params(password) = pwd
params(username) = james
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Donal's suggestion, sharing the spirit, but building on battery pieces: [`tcllib` `rest` package](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/rest/rest.md#10):

(1) To process the query (as part of a valid URL)

```
% package req rest
1.3.1
% set query [rest::parameters ?username=jo%3Dhn]; # http:// is default scheme, ? is minimum URL boilerplate
username jo%3Dhn
```

(2) Run a URL decoder (e.g., the one by Donal or the one from [Rosetta code](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/URL_decoding#Tcl)):

```
% proc urlDecode {str} {
   set specialMap {"[" "%5B" "]" "%5D"}
   set seqRE {%([0-9a-fA-F]{2})}
   set replacement {[format "%c" [scan "\1" "%2x"]]}
   set modStr [regsub -all $seqRE [string map $specialMap $str] $replacement]
   return [encoding convertfrom utf-8 [subst -nobackslash -novariable $modStr]]
}
```

then:

```
% set info [lmap v $query {urlDecode $v}]
username jo=hn
% dict get $info username
jo=hn
```